# ASP How do I insert a username into a table?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm struggling with my code below, I'm reading the logged on users username and trying to insert their name into a SQL table called licenses, the table contains 2 columns 1 contains license numbers the other is all nulls at the moment but a username should be inserted along side one when this page loads. Currently the page just loops constantly and nothing is inserted into the table. The user inside connection1.asp does have read/write access to the database.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" LCID=1033%>
<%
aName = Split(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"), "\")
user = aName(UBound(aName))
user = UCase(user)
Erase aName
%>
<!--#include file="Connections/connection1.asp" -->
<%
Dim Recordset1
Dim Recordset1_numRows
Set Recordset1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Recordset1.ActiveConnection = MM_connection1_STRING
Recordset1.Source = "SELECT * FROM Licenses2 WHERE userid = '" & user & "';"
Recordset1.Open()
%>
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY leftmargin="5" onLoad="setTimeout('reloadFunction()',500000)">

<% Do While NOT Recordset1.EOF %>
<% strUserName =(Recordset1.Fields.Item("userid").Value)%>
<% response.write strUserName %>'s Serial Number:

<% strSerial =(Recordset1.Fields.Item("serial").Value)%>
<% response.write strSerial %>
<% Recordset1.movenext %>

<% loop %>

<%
If strUserName = user then 
    'record found do nothing
    'response.write "user found"
else
    adoCon.Execute =  "SET ROWCOUNT 1; UPDATE Licenses2 SET userid = '" & user & "' WHERE userid = 'NULL';"
    Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "3" 
End if
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<%
Recordset1.Close()
Set Recordset1 = Nothing
Set Recordset2 = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: cough... SQL injection... at the very least you might want to replace ' with nothing or ''... unlikely attack but still possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is NOT found, should you be doing an INSERT instead of UPDATE?

If the UPDATE is correct, change the last NULL ... remove the quotes. Right now you are comparing a STRING value of `'NULL'` instead of the value `NULL` and it should be IS NULL

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1; UPDATE Licenses2 SET userid = '" & user & "' WHERE userid IS NULL;
```

Also, see if you can comment out the `<BODY ... >` tag and create a new one without the RELOADFUNCTION and see if that makes a difference.

Lastly, read up on SQL Injection because your code is prone to Injection attacks. Search on StackOverflow.com for SQL Injection and you will find plenty of explanations, examples and cures.

Comment: I changed 'NULL' to NULL with no change. I think UPDATE is correct as the record exists with a license in the first column. Thanks

Comment: it should be an IS NULL check - I have changed it above.

Answer (score 0):

Check if LOGON_USER is actually returning any data. If you have IIS security set to 'Anonymous' access then this will not be populated with anything.

Your code would also be potentially prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: LOGON_USER is returning a user name. Thanks